# PHP - PDO, how to return the number of rows in a select statement

Tags: php, pdo

I have a simple statement but cant seem to get the number of rows from the select statement, really bugging me when its really simple. I keep getting empty string.

Here is the code

```
include "connect.php";

$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$threadID = $_POST['threadID'];

$sql1 = "select * from AT_AddThread where AT_ID = :threadID";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->execute(array(':threadID' => $threadID));
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn(7);
//echo $result;

$sql2 = "select * from TJ_ThreadJoined where TJ_T_ID = :threadID"
$q2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
$q2->execute(array(':threadID' => $threadID));
$q2->execute();
$rows = $q2->fetchColumn();
echo $rows; //THIS IS where i want to return the number of rows from the select statement
```

Comment: [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)  for `$conn->rowCount` although its not completely reliable as it does not work will all database engines

Comment: There is a metod for that: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php but it is not guaranteed to work with all db engines.

Comment: there must be another way then?

Comment: `->rowCount()` is *technically* for retrieving the last number of rows affected by an INSERT or UPDATE statement however some database servers will return it for a SELECT. `fetchColumn` according to the docs : *Returns a single column from the next row of a result set* so you couldn't really do a count on that anyway - it would always be 1 (i.e. the next row). You'd bet better of merely selecting **only** the columns you want in the SQL and then using `fetch()` in a loop or `fetchAll()` and counting the array size returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to fetchColumn you can try the following ways:

1. count the rows

   `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
   echo "count = "  . count($rows);`
2. Use `rowCount()`

   `echo "count = "  . $stmt->rowCount();`
3. Add it to the query :

   `SELECT COUNT(*) as rowCount ...`

   `echo $row['rowCount'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`echo $q2->rowCount();`

or

```
$row = $q2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo $row[0];
```

.

`->rowCount();` [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can always get number of rows returned in last query. Just add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` after `SELECT` statement

```
$sql2 = "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from TJ_ThreadJoined where TJ_T_ID = :threadID"
```

Then execute query `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`, fetch row and you will have number of rows from last query.